# How to execute a unit test several times in a single test run?

Tags: unit-testing, batch-file, mstest

One of my tests is intermittently failing. I now want to execute the test frequently.

I wrote a little batch file

```
:loop
mstest /testcontainer:"path/test.dll" /test:"mytest"
set /a COUNT=%COUNT%+1
if %COUNT GTR %MAX% goto end
goto loop
```

While this works fine, though the output isn't meaningful or telling. Let's assume I run this test 100 times I get 100 times a text saying

```
Loading ... 
Starting execution ...
Results
Passed/Failed 1
--------
Total 1
```

And 100 .trx files will be created...

What I actually want is having an output like this

```
Passed 97
Failed 3
--------
Total 100
```

and just one .trx file.

I somehow doubt that it's possible to run a test several times in a single test run at all since I didn't find any parameter on `mstest /help` output.

Is there a way to create an output as close as possible to the given request?

Comment: You really should concentrate on fixing the code that leads to the intermittent failures...

Comment: Tests should be deterministic, i.e. have one result. Software usually shouldn't act like Schroedinger's Cat.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth And that's why I need a batch that runs the test frequently...

Comment: I don't follow. You need to run the test frequently to fix those intermittent failures? Why?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Well, since the failure happened too seldom (timing issue) I need to run the test as often as possible, especially for validating that it has been fixed. Or what else do you suggest?

Comment: It's a hack but you could turn the test into a data-driven test and feed it a file with 100 rows of data - you don't have to do anything with the data; the simple fact it's there should cause mstest to run the test 100 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set passed=0
set failed=0
for /l %%x in (1,1,%max%) do (
  mstest /testcontainer:"path/test.dll" /test:"mytest"
  if !errorlevel!==0 (
    set /a passed=passed+1
  ) else (
    set /a failed=failed+1
  )
)
echo Passed %passed% > %~n1.trx
echo Failed %failed% >> %~n1.trx
echo --------- >> %~n1.trx
echo Total %Max% >> %~n1.trx
endlocal
```